# Xcode errors not identifying the line of code with the issue

Tags: swift, xcode

I am having trouble with Xcode and identifying the source of the error. It will flag an error, but no longer identifies the specific line of code that is the problem. It used to, but it no longer does. An example is included.

[example of what I see when i get an error. none of the x marks id's the line of code with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYGTm.png)

As a newcomer, it would help tremendously for me to understand the line of the code that is the source of the issue. This was a feature previously available, but it no longer is for me. This feels like a simple settings issue, but I can not solve it. Any insights would be appreciated. I am running Xcode 13, Swift 5; the MacOS is Big Sur 11.6 (note this problem has been ongoing - i've just reached my frustration level tonight).

Comment: I don't think that is a settings issue. I'd try deleting all Derived Data and restarting Xcode. If those don't work, I'd pare down your file to be as minimal as possible (to where you *know* there aren't errors) and then add code back in until the compiler throws an error again. It's *probably* just the Swift compiler getting overwhelmed by something it doesn't know how to parse correctly or figure out.

Comment: Similarly, just to narrow it down to an issue in your main project, you could start with an *empty project* and add a non-compiling line to see if it correctly highlights it -- my suspicion is that it *will* with a simple enough project.

Comment: 1/ For what it's worth, Xcode 13.1 started throwing some ambiguous errors, similar but *not* exactly like this. (I think it's how it uses Swift 5.5 and will be corrected.) I never had *build* error issues with Xcode 13.0 though. My best advice - if you can afford it - is a form of "save early, save often".... build frequently, after making one change, be it one line or 10 lines. That's how I get around this. Coupled with using source control, you can pretty much narrow down where the issue is.

Comment: 2/ A bit of history going backwards. In 2018 Apple introduced SwiftUI. It was worse that your issue! It *would* point to a line of code - many many times the wrong one. It also would give an explicit error description - many times wrong. Hopefully it's improved since. In 2014 Apple introduced the Swift language, which has since become open source. That was almost - but IMHO not - as "rough around the edges as SwiftUI. @jnpdx has some good ideas like my first comment does. Sometimes I'll get stung by "doing too much" in between builds and commits. Good luck!

Comment: Use the sidebar to the left and select the Report navigator to see what it has to say about the error.

Comment: Did you clean the build folder, as I suggested earlier? That sometimes helps. Even better, quit Xcode and throw away the whole DerivedData folder.

Comment: And please don't do special pleading in your question. If you think someone is harassing you, flag for a moderator.

Comment: @dfd - thanks, I do follow your suggestion, to save early and often, which is a way of finding the line with the error. Not the best way, but it works. 

This is really becoming a problem for me when I try to add more functions to an existing project, and I have to go back to make unanticipated fixes. I'd thought I'd ask to see if others had suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: @ElTomato - thanks, I've tried that, too, but it will not identify the line of code with the error, only that there is an error and what it is.

Comment: @jnpdx - Thanks - I should have added that I have deleted all the Derived Data for another project. I was having difficulty with an unwind segue, and I saw another post of someone who had the same problem, and they received the suggestion to delete the Derived Data. It didn't work for my unwind segue, nor did it work for this. Also, I tried rebuilding from scratch, too (this project is a dummy one where I practice so as not to wreck my main one). Still no luck, but thank you for your kind suggestion